# Creating MySQL database with variables

Tags: mysql, database, variables

I want to do something along the lines of

`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS @database_name;`

From reading [the mysql syntax for prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) it appears that they cant be used to create databases, otherwise something like this would have been ok.

```
SET @s = CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ',@database_name);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Ideally I want it as something [I can run from a .sql file](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,160002,228438#msg-228438) from a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSQL="mysql"
`${MYSQL} --version >& /dev/null`
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    MYSQL="mysql5"
    `${MYSQL} --version > /dev/null`
    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "Can't find mysql binary?"
        exit 1
    fi
fi

 ${MYSQL} -u root --password=###### -e "set @database_name:='ben_search';source CreateSkeleton.sql;"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is to put placeholder in your `.sql` file and use shell to replace them with your database name before passing the file to mysql.

Comment: Seems similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15249929/277307), although that is with a procedure.  I tried your prepared statement with MySQL 5.5.19, and it appeared to work.  Are you getting an error with the prepared statement?

Comment: Ah, I looked at the documentation link a bit closer.  Looks like MySQL 5.5 [supports a number of statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) that weren't supported in 5.0.  So, to be clear, MySQL 5.5 will support prepared statements with `CREATE DATABASE`.

Answer (score 2):

You could just take the `CREATE DATABASE` statement away from your SQL file and issue it from your shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dbname='my_db'
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE $dbname"
mysql $dbname < /path/to/file/CreateSkeleton.sql
```

Comment: I know this is an old question and I hope you found a solution by then... I'm just trying to relieve my compulsive need for closure.